# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMVDetector" referenced from: TextDetector

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, google-vision, google-ios-vision

I included Google Firebase MLKit to my project without cocoapods. When I try to build, I'm getting the `Undefined symbol` error: [Xcode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvxr3.png)

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMVDetector", referenced from:
      l45918 in TextDetector
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVDetector", referenced from:
      l45917 in TextDetector
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVFeature", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVTextBlockFeature in TextDetector
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVTextLineFeature in TextDetector
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVTextElementFeature in TextDetector
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GMVFeature", referenced from:
      l45914 in TextDetector
      l45915 in TextDetector
      l45916 in TextDetector
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVUtility", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TextDetector
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GMVLogger", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in TextDetector
  "_GMVFeatureTypeTextLine", referenced from:
      l31298 in TextDetector
  "_GMVDetectorImageOrientation", referenced from:
      l31341 in TextDetector
      l31342 in TextDetector
  "_GMVFeatureTypeTextElement", referenced from:
      l31313 in TextDetector
  "_GMVFeatureTypeTextBlock", referenced from:
      l31279 in TextDetector
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So far I have tried :

1. Quitting Xcode and then clean build
2. Manual and also drag & drop of frameworks
3. Linked all the required resource folders
4. Deleting the Xcode temp files
5. Set `symbols hidden by default` under `Build Settings` to `No`
   Although the framework `TextDetector` is linked to the right target.

All these does not seems to work. I followed [Integrate without CocoaPods](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks) for the framework setup.

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggIE4.png) and [Architecture in Build Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5S8e.png)

Comment: Please share an image of your project and target's build settings, where it says `'Architecture'` and `'Valid Architectures'`

Comment: @George_E_2 I have edited my post with screenshots.

Comment: It appears to me as though you have some Objective-C code which is not compatible with armv7. Are you calling some invalid obj-c functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved. I added all the other frameworks which were that came along with `.zip` file in the above mentioned link of Firebase. [List of Frameworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9iBR.png). This is not a straightforward setup and is neither mentioned in `readme` nor in the website. May be all these frameworks are not required but many are inter dependent as they are specified in `module.modulemap` of each framework.